# Relatively position a div within a fixed div?

Tags: html, css

I have this fixed gradient div that all my content must go within in order for this cursor position element to continue working. The problem is I want the content to scroll and not be fixed. How can I achieve this?

Here is what I have:

```
    <body>

        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="gradient">
            <div class="logo">
              <img src="logo-05.svg">
            </div>

            <div class="statement">
              This is a blockquote. Someone said something really funny and it should be noted here. Aenean massa strong . Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In em enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam link dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. This is a blockquote. Someone said something really funny and it should be noted here. Aenean massa strong . Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In em enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam link dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. 
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>


    .gradient {
      height: calc(100%);
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(270deg, #FFCC33,#FF3366);
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(270deg, #FFCC33,#FF3366);
      background: -o-linear-gradient(270deg, #FFCC33,#FF3366);
      background: -ms-linear-gradient(270deg, #FFCC33,#FF3366);
      background: linear-gradient(180deg, #FFCC33,#FF3366);
      position: fixed;
      width: 100%;
        background-color: #292c2f;
      font-family: monospace;
      overflow: hidden;
      font-size: 100pt;
      color: white;
      z-index: -99;
    }

.wrapper{
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  position: relative;
}

.header{
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}

.dates{
  color:black;
  z-index: 99;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  padding-top: 5px;
  font-size: 20pt;
  margin-left: -20px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 1pt;
}


.year{
  color:black;
  margin-top: -10px;
  z-index: 99;
 display: inline-block;
  top:25px;
  font-size: 55pt;
  margin-left: 20px;
  font-family: 'Kavoon', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 800;
  letter-spacing:-3px;
}

.location{
right: 35px;
top: 35px;
text-align: right;
width: 100%;
position: fixed;
font-size: 20pt;
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
font-weight: 400;
color: black;
}

.logo{
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  width: 600px;
  position: relative;
}

.statement{
  position: relative;
  font-size: 14pt;
  color:black;
  width:500px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.footer ul {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14pt;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 800;
  width:100%;
  display:inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;

}
.footer-wrap{
  color:black;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 45px;
  bottom: 0;
  position: fixed;
  padding:10;

    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change your property `overflow:hidden;` to `overflow: scroll;` in your `.gradient` class.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r469cw29/).